# Cannot search for pairs with searchpairpos()

Tags: neovim, vimscript-lua

I am trying to search for the location of the start and the end of a pair with `searchpairpos()`. Given an example like this:

```
*hel[]lo*
```

And my code like this:

```lua
local start_match = vim.api.nvim_call_function('searchpairpos', {"*", "", "*", "zncb"})
local end_match = vim.api.nvim_call_function('searchpairpos', {"*", "", "*", "znc"})
```

I am only able to search for the `start_match`, `end_match[1]` and `end_match[2]` always return `0` (i.e no match). I guess it is the flag that is causing this issue, but I am not sure how to fix it.

Comment: I just had a quick look in the vim 8.2 help doc for searchpairpos() and I didn't see anything about a 'z' flag, only 'b,c,n,s,w,W,r,m'. Are you sure there is such a thing as a 'z' flag? (it's possible I missed it, or that's it's a Neovim only feature).

Comment: The arguments are patterns, so I would expect you need `'\*'`

Comment: In addition to the above comment, searchpairpos() does not work when the `start` and `end` have the same pattern. Use searchpos() instead.